# Why doesn't my .htaccess file redirect properly?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

This is my code:

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(admin)
RewriteRule !maintenance\.php$ /maintenance.php [R=301,L]
```

I want to redirect all traffic on the site to maintenance.php except for any requests for files in /admin. I've tried so many combinations that never work. It always redirects no matter what. I can't figure out what could be causing this.

UPDATE:
I figured something out. If I comment out the .htaccess in the admin folder, Ben's code works. Here's the code there:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted area"
AuthUserFile "/home1/user/.htpasswds/public_html/example/admin/passwd"
require valid-user
```

What can I do to this .htaccess file to allow it to work?

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: That hasn't fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use permanent redirect `R=301` in this purpose, you site is not maintenance permanently. Use temporary redirect `R=302` only, otherwise your users will always see maintenance page even if you remove this rule, because `R=301` is cached by browser.

`%{REQUEST_URI}` starts with `/`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance.php$
RewriteRule ^ /maintenance.php [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Cleared all browser data and swapped out the code for yours, and it still redirects to maintenance.php when trying to access example.com/admin/adminPage.php Testing form a device that's never been on the site before, it does the same thing.

Comment: do you have any other rewriterule on .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use this line   `DirectoryIndex maintenance.php`  in .htaccess in order to redirect to this page . ones your site is ready you can remove maintenance mode by commenting the above line

Comment: I don't want any pages in example.com to be accessible except files in /admin. If I just wanted to prevent access to the index page I could rename maintenance.php to index.php but that isn't what I'm looking for.